# Producer and Consumer shared queue with values coming from HttpRequest

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, producer-consumer

This is the classic problem of Producer/Consumer. I start both threads when I bootstrap my Spring Boot application. I just want to write from Producer thread into the shared queue when I receive a httpRequest. So, how can I pass this value to my Producer thread in order that I can put it in the shared queue?. Is it possible?

**Main Class**

```
public class ProducerConsumerPattern {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // create shared object
        BlockingQueue sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

        // create Producer and Consumer Thread
        Thread prodThread = new Thread(new Producer(sharedQueue));
        Thread consThread = new Thread(new Consumer(sharedQueue));

        // start producer and Consumer thread
        prodThread.start();
        consThread.start();
    }
}
```

**Consumer Class**

```
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue sharedQueue;

    public Consumer (BlockingQueue sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Consumed: "+ sharedQueue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Producer Class**

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue sharedQueue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // I don't want to write in the queue the counter values.
        // I want to put my own values, when I receive them from outside **
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Produced: " + i);
                sharedQueue.put(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the http param through `@RestController` and `@RequestMapping`, but how can I get Producer thread and put this new value into the queue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get handle of producer for pushing any item to queue. Write a method in producer to push item:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue sharedQueue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    public void pushItem(int item) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Produced: " + item);
        sharedQueue.put(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //I don't want to write in the queue the counter values. I want to put my own values, when I receive them from outside **
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            try {
                System.out.println("Produced: " + i);
                sharedQueue.put(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in main method you need to write:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //Creating shared object
        BlockingQueue sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

        //Creating Producer and Consumer Thread
        Producer producer = new Producer(sharedQueue);
        Thread prodThread = new Thread(producer);
        Thread consThread = new Thread(new Consumer(sharedQueue));

        //Starting producer and Consumer thread
        prodThread.start();
        consThread.start();

        producer.pushItem(2000);
    }
```

The item `2000` will be pushed by main thread but the order is not guaranteed. The output for a sample run is:

`Produced: 0
Produced: 2000
Produced: 1
Produced: 2
Produced: 3
Consumed: 0
Produced: 4
Consumed: 2000
Produced: 5
Produced: 6
Consumed: 1
Produced: 7
Consumed: 2
Produced: 8
Produced: 9
Consumed: 3
Consumed: 4
Consumed: 5
Consumed: 6
Consumed: 7
Consumed: 8
Consumed: 9`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I execute that code and start the threads when I bootstrap my Spring Boot app. I don't want to push the item that time. I want to push new items asynchronously, when I get a httprequest from any of my endpoints with @restcontroller, once the threads are already running. Sorry if I'm not enough clear

Comment: @jamlet: You need to get handle of the producer and then you can call method `pushItem` wherever and whenever you want to. I have just shown an example here. You can pass the reference of producer to some other method as well.

Comment: to be honest, I don't know how to get handle of the producer out there. And another question is, inside the run method of the producer, as I don't want to do anything there, I just leave it: while(true){ }?